# get list of sub-set dict from existing list of dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There is a list of dict like below, with each dict contains two keys.

```
original_list = [
    {
        'label': 'First Name',
        'value': 'Leo',
    },
    {
        'label': 'Last Name',
        'value': 'Lee',
    },
    {
        'label': 'Gender',
        'value': 'Male',
    },
    {
        'label': 'Age',
        'value': 35,
    },
    {
        'label': 'Telephone',
        'value': '13788995566',
    }
]
```

I want to get a new list of dict with only one key('label') in the dict.

```
# expecting output like below
new_list =  [
    {
        'label': 'First Name'
    },
    {
        'label': 'Last Name'
    },
    {
        'label': 'Gender'
    },
    {
        'label': 'Age'
    },
    {
        'label': 'Telephone'
    }
]
```

I know one way to get around.

```
new_list = [{'label': d['label']} for d in original_list]
print(new_list)
```

Is there any method more convenient?

If the original_list data is in one pandas DataFrame, how to get the same result?

Answer (score 1):

If input is `DataFrame` select columns for output by subset `[[]]` and call [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with parameter `orient='records'`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(original_list)
print (df)
        label        value
0  First Name          Leo
1   Last Name          Lee
2      Gender         Male
3         Age           35
4   Telephone  13788995566

print (df[['label']].to_dict(orient='records'))
[{'label': 'First Name'}, 
 {'label': 'Last Name'}, 
 {'label': 'Gender'}, 
 {'label': 'Age'}, 
 {'label': 'Telephone'}]
```

Comment: Thanks. I just know the 'orient' option.

Comment: if the label are not unique we can do this [{'label':label} for label in df['label'].unique()]

Answer (score 1):

Just like yours! List comprehension, Even bit lengthier :) But definitely one more approach :)

```
[{e: i} for d in original_list for e,i in d.items() if e =='label']
```